# How to train HMM for ECG beat types generation?

Tags: classification, hidden-markov-model

I've read papers on using a regular Markov Model to do this, manually defining the transition matrix. I wanted to use a Hidden Markov Model to more accurately capture these transition probabilities from real data with Baum-Welch.

However, seeing other works like using around 20 states to train a HMM just to detect the presence of ischemia and feeding it sequences of a fixed number of samples from different ECG beats has gotten me confused on the number of states I should use and how should I turn the ECG signal into a training sequence.

Let's say I want to produce N beat types. Can I, just as an example, train an N-hidden state model, with a discrete sequence of intervals in which each interval corresponds to the difference between a "normal" heart cycle template signal and a real heart cycle signal (e.g. low, medium or high) segmented from a continuous ECG signal with each of the N types? Or maybe the instantaneous heart rate of each cycle?